# 'xmlrpclib.Fault: Request contains to few param' error when using ldtp

Tags: python, automated-tests, xml-rpc, ui-automation

I've been trying to use the Windows implementation of [LDTP (Cobra)](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra) for testing a stand-alone application within Python. It seems to work fine at first, albeit running slow most of the time. For example I was able to select menu items:

```
selectmenuitem('Sample App','File;New')
```

However, when I tried to execute any of the following lines:

```
waittillguiexist('Sample App', 'btnOK')
rightclick('Sample App','tblcBRANCH')
```

I get the following error in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ldtp\client.py", line 69, in __call__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\ldtp\client.py", line 186, in request
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 0: 'Request contains too few param elements based on
  method signature.'>
```

I assume that I may still encounter this error with other functions. Are there any problems with my installation of LDTP? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this project, arguments were missing for the API you are using, please [refer](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/user-doc/db/df8/a00076.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow! Answers should have the essential parts of a linked website, as links sometimes become outdated and break.

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem, too. My solution is from python folder (C:\python2.7\lib\sites-packages) delete ldtp-xxx.egg, and remove the entry from easy_install file. Reinstall CobraWinLDTP-3.5.0. Then the problem is solved.